# Cannot move files from gcloud VM Instance to laptop

Tags: ssh, gcloud

I can move files from my laptop to a gcloud VM instance just fine, the other way around however is not so easy.  According to this website I am to use this syntax:

```
scp -i ~/.ssh/my-ssh-key username@ip-address:remote-file-path local-file-path
```

I have done all that.  At first I got the warning:

> The authenticity of host 99.99.99.99 can't be established.
>   ECDSA key fingerprint is zzzzz
>   Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
>   Warning: Permanently added 99.99.99.99 (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.

Then I got the error message:

> kylefoley@99.99.99.99: Permission denied (publickey).

I am putting these commands in the terminal of my local laptop.  I then went and changed all of the permissions for each folder, subfolder and file.  But that did not help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't why the above syntax did not work but the following syntax does work in command line

gcloud compute scp --zone us-west2-a [instance-name]:[path-to-file] [local-path]

That incidentally was the syntax I was using to move files from the laptop to the vm instance but I did not think it would work.